Check if the matrix containing moments of random variable is positive semi-definite
Let $X$ be a continuous random variable taking value in $\mathbb{R}.$ The $X$ has finite forth moment. Then, check if the following matrix is positive semi-definite.
$$ A:=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \mathbb{E}[X] & \mathbb{E}[X^2]\\
\mathbb{E}[X] & \mathbb{E}[X^2] & \mathbb{E}[X^3]\\
\mathbb{E}[X^2] & \mathbb{E}[X^3] & \mathbb{E}[X^4]
\end{bmatrix}   
$$
where $\mathbb{E}[\cdot]$ denotes expectation.
I have tried to check using argument related to non-negativity of principal minors of $A$ but was not able to prove the non-negativity of determinant of $A$.

One can observe that the determinant of $A$ is
$$
\det(A) = \left( \mathbb{E}[X^2] \, \mathbb{E}[X^4] - \left( \mathbb{E}[X^3] \right)^2 \right) - \left( \left(\mathbb{E}[X]\right)^2 \, \mathbb{E}[X^4] - 2 \, \mathbb{E}[X] \, \mathbb{E}[X^2] \, \mathbb{E}[X^3] + \left( \mathbb{E}[X^2] \right)^3 \right) .
$$
While $\left( \mathbb{E}[X^2] \, \mathbb{E}[X^4] - \left( \mathbb{E}[X^3] \right)^2 \right)$ is non-negative by an application of Cauchy Schwarz, I am unable to prove the same for the remaining part.
However, if you know that covariance matrices have non-negative determinants, what you want follows from the fact that $\det(A)$ equals the the determinant of
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\operatorname{Var}(X) & \operatorname{Cov}\left(X, X^2\right) \\
\operatorname{Cov}\left(X, X^2\right) & \operatorname{Var}\left(X^2\right)
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Alternatively, a nicer solution in my opinion, is to note that for random variables $X$ and $Y$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}$, the expected value of their product $\mathbb{E}[XY]$ can be seen as an inner product $\langle X,Y\rangle$. Then,
$$ A:=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \mathbb{E}[X] & \mathbb{E}[X^2]\\
\mathbb{E}[X] & \mathbb{E}[X^2] & \mathbb{E}[X^3]\\
\mathbb{E}[X^2] & \mathbb{E}[X^3] & \mathbb{E}[X^4]
\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ X \\ X^2 \\\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & X & X^2\\\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Hence, $A$ is a Gram matrix, which are known to be positive semi-definite, and this is easy to prove (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix). This is nice, because this answers the question in the more general setting where you have the analogous $n\times n$ matrix of $A$.
